# When I run tests it complains in the CircleCi, but not on my local machine?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, acl, circleci

We have this acl file which is no or less the same in every other application that I have.

```
if (!defined('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
define('ROLE_ADMIN', 'admin');
}
if (!defined('ROLE_MASTER')) {
define('ROLE_MASTER', 'master');
}
if (!defined('ROLE_REGULAR')) {
define('ROLE_REGULAR', 'regular');
}
if (!defined('EDITION_ALL,')) {
define('EDITION_ALL,', ['CXEE1502-de','CXPE1502-de','CXTE1502-de','CXBE1502-de']);
}

return [
'acl' => [
    'index' => [
        'index' => [
            'roles' => [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MASTER, ROLE_REGULAR],
            'products' => EDITION_ALL,
        ]
    ],
    'dashboards' => [
        'dashboard' => [
            'roles' => [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MASTER, ROLE_REGULAR],
            'products' => EDITION_ALL,
        ]
    ],
]
]
```

CircleCi is complaining regarding the value EDITION_ALL. 
This is the exact message that I got:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant EDITION_ALL - assumed
>   'EDITION_ALL'
>   Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Don't you have a misspell (a coma inside the constant name) in `'EDITION_ALL,'`?

Comment: Yes, I have misspelled and I am sorry about that. Anyhow this bug is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using on circleCi machine php 5.6. and in my local development I am using php 7.0.13. which is why this has happen. 
I was a bit misleading in the question. Sorry for that.